# t-test of control group and treated group

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

If I do a t-test of the control and treated group to get the mean, difference, and p-value. How do I know if there is good comparability between groups?

Comment: "good comparability" is awfully vague. What question are you actually trying to answer? The question a t test can begin to answer is whether you have evidence that the two means are not the same (if you accept a bunch of assumptions). Is that the question you want answered?

Comment: Your hypothesis could be "good comparability" such as $\mu_1=\mu_2$ between the two groups, then you can use the $t$ test to check if your hypothesis is reasonable under some assumptions.